# Mock controller that implements base controller properties using Moq

Tags: c#, moq

This is an attempt to mock up a test on a controller method/function that relies on some properties that are implemented in the base controller. The code to test the controller method works fine, just no values populated from the base controller.

Here is mock setup:

```
SampleController controller = new SampleController(); // SampleController has a base controller

// call to method below
var mockHttpCtxt = MockHelpers.MockHttpCtxt("/somepath/addpath", "stringval");

controller.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext(mockHttpCtxt.Object, new System.Web.Routing.RouteData(), new Mock<BaseController>().Object);

controller.CallSomeMethod();
```

Below is the helper method for setting up the context. The issue is that when the `controller.CallSomeMethod();` executes, the properties/values from the base controller have not been initialized.

```
public static Mock<HttpContextBase> MockHttpCtxt(string url= null, string val = null)
{
    var httpContext = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
    var mockRequest = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>();
    mockRequest.Setup(x => x.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath).Returns(url);
    mockRequest.Setup(x => x.Headers).Returns(new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection());
    mockRequest.Setup(x => x.Cookies).Returns(new HttpCookieCollection());
    mockRequest.Setup(x => x.QueryString).Returns(new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection());
    mockRequest.Setup(x => x.Form).Returns(new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection());
    mockRequest.Setup(x => x.HttpMethod).Returns(HttpMethod.Post.Method);
    mockRequest.Setup(x => x.IsAuthenticated).Returns(true);
    mockRequest.Setup(x => x.InputStream.Position).Returns(0);
    mockRequest.Setup(x => x.ContentType).Returns("application/json; charset=utf-8");
    httpContext.Setup(x => x.User.Identity.Name).Returns(stringval);
    httpContext.Setup(x => x.Request).Returns(mockRequest.Object);

    return httpContext;
}
```

The SampleController implements a base controller like so
`public class SampleController : BaseController` 
and in the base controller is
`protected static SomeVals CustomVals => SomeVals.PopulateVals();`
where the PopulateVals simply adds a collection of values.

How should this mock test be setup to initialize the base controller properties/values? When I currently execute in the mock, the CustomVals is null. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to mock `SomeVals.PopulateVals()`

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Thanks for the reply Chetan, after mocking the ```SomeVals.PopultateVals()``` How do I get that mocked collection of values attached to my mocked ```SampleController```? The idea being that I can use those mocked values in the method of the controller when the method is invoked/executed. Sorry, kind of new to the mock (moq) world. Thanks in advance.